# How to make a downloadable link (preferably the file name) from an image data retrieved from database PHP

Tags: php, html

This is the image data retrieved from the database. 
I want this to be the file name which is downloadable when clicked:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code for uploading the image:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  include 'db1.php';
  if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
      $docFile =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
      $filetype = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

      $docCode = $_POST['docCode'];
      $docType = $_POST['docType'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $comment = $_POST['comment'];
      $dateWrit = $_POST['dateWrit'];
      $signatory = $_POST['signatory'];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO document (docCode, docType, docFile,fileType, subject, dateWrit, signatory,comment, status,staffid)
              VALUES ('$docCode', '$docType', '{$docFile}','{$filetype['mime']}', '$subject', '$dateWrit', '$signatory','$comment', 'Unsent', '".$_SESSION['staffid']."')";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Succesfully added!')</script>";

      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }

      $conn->close();
```

and I called the data from the database:

```
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['docCode']."</td>
           <td>".$row['docType']."</td>
           <td>".$row['subject']."</td>
           <td>".$row['dateWrit']."</td>
           <td>".$row['signatory']."</td>
           <td> <a href=".$row['docFile']." download>".$row['docFile']."</a></td>
           <td>".$row['comment']."</td>
           <td>".$row['status']."</td>";
```

Comment: Use `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); ` in order to download the file ... change filename with the wanted one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dump a raw image into an `href` attribute and turn it into a download. The `href` is supposed to store a URL, not raw data.

You're going to have to set up a handler page to echo out the image data and apply appropriate headers. For example, set up a page that retrieves the image data in `$row`, then do something like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");

// TODO: get the image here, based on some $_GET or $_POST parameter, and
// load it into $row

echo $row['docFile'];
```

(The above code is not meant to be exact, as the code in your question is pretty unclear regarding how you set `$row` and where, if anywhere, you save the image's name.)

Also, very important: you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Please read about it and use prepared statements to avoid having someone hack or hose your database.

Finally, be aware that many people consider it best practice note to store binary blobs (like images) in the database, but only a path to the file on the system. Passing binary data back and forth causes lots of problems, not least of which is bloating your database and putting a lot of load on it whenever you want to read an image.